Excel: finding a value on sheet 2, if a combination happens in sheet 1
I have a set of values combinations in 1 sheet (countries from and to) and another sheet with combinations and values of those combinations.
What I need is, when a combination happens in sheet 1, and is found on sheet 2, to bring the value into sheet 1.
So for example, here I have the combos I would need the value:
working table
value table
the result should be:
working tables with values from value table

Try: =XLOOKUP(1,(A2=Sheet2!A:A)*(B2=Sheet2!B:B),Sheet2!C:C,"")

You can use SUMPRODUCT formula, like: =SUMPRODUCT((E$2:E$5=A2)*(F$2:F$5=B2),G$2:G$5).

